# AWS Cloudformation dynamic resource name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am looking to try and create a factory template for several instances which will change only by parameters passed to a template. However I later need to refer to the resource to get a specific output from it.

I am not sure that if a resource specifies a templateURL which then has another resource in it whether this resource is the only resource which will contain the output or whether that is indeed passed up the ladder. I suspect the former.

So I was thinking about trying to make the resource name dynamic pehraps **myresourcebase-var** or something. Is this possible?

Comment: My initial response is that resource names are not dynamic, but can you perhaps restate the question in terms of the problem you're trying to solve?  Usually, if it feels too hard, you're going about it the wrong way...

Answer (score 0):

You could tag your resources with 'var' and then when you need to find those resources again  search for them based on that tag.